# jquery - finding if element is in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, dom-traversal

im trying to find out how to see if an error is returned from an AJAX request.
for testing the request always returns `<p id="error">test</p>`

I thought you could do it like this:

```
//html is the var which contains the result
var DOM = $(html);
if( $('#error', DOM ).length != 0 ) {
    alert(html);    
}
```

but this does not work. Can anyone shine a light on whats going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your HTML isn't wrapped in something (like a `div`) then it needs to be.

```
var html = '<div></div><p id="error">ERROR!</p><span>other stuff</span>';

var DOM= $('<div>' + html + '</div>');
if( $('#error', DOM).length != 0 ) {
    alert(html);    
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/exqTD/

(I thought `wrap` would help here but it doesn't. If anyone knows why then point it out).

Alternatively, the selector context is implemented using [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/), so you could just do:

```
if( DOM.find('#error').length != 0 ) {
    alert(html);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not inserted to the DOM, so you cannot look it up with a selector.

You could try to use a simple regex with the test() function on the variable.

```
if (html.test(/id="error"/i)) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this will help:

```
$('body').append('<div class="hidden_div">'+html+'</div>');
if($('#error',$('.hidden_div')).size()>0){
  alert(html);
}
```

Just add in the css

```
.hidden_div{display:none;}
```

and that should be it, oh and you can use `.length` or `.size()`

or you can just use:

```
if(html.indexOf('id="error"')>-1){alert('yes we have an error!');}
```

Cheers

G.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find function:

```
if ( $(html).find("#error").length != 0 )
{
    alert(html);    
}
```