# Find if selector exists in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you find out if the data retreived from a `.get()` request contains html with a certain selector?

```
 $.get(url,function(data){   alert( data.find("#myid").length )  });
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Don't you have a "find method not found" error in your console ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery - finding if element is in variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624090/jquery-finding-if-element-is-in-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing data is some HTML, use

```
$(data).find("#myid").length
```

or this more reliable solution if your document isn't well formed :

```
$("<div>").html(data).find("#myid")
```

Comment: Would be safer to do `$("<div>").html(data).find("#myid")` just in case the element could potentially be on the top level. also avoids possible issues due to the format of the html with the new restrictions on `$()`

Comment: @KevinB Yes, edited (although I don't know what are the "new restrictions"). It also helps if the document isn't really a document but a bunch of tags.

Comment: Actually, I found Kevin's suggestion to work, because I was having html formatting issues, wasn't working like the answer originally suggests. Thanks Kevin.

Comment: The new restrictions are if there are any words at the start or end of the html, it will not pull in the html properly. (words will be missing). that doesn't really affect this particular case due to targeting a child element though. Safer to just do it anyway and get in the habit. Alternatively `$.parseHTML()` works too.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing `$(data).find`